# How to fade in/fade out a single model when a $scope.items is updated in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, fadein, fadeout

I have just started out with Angular JS for my web application.

I have a list of objects which are rendered using `<div ng-repeat="item in items">...</div>`.The `$scope.items` list is populated using an ajax call to the server.

My module is injected with ngAnimate as below

```
var myApp = angular.module('myModule',['ngAnimate','infinite-scroll']);
```

There is an option for the user to add/delete an item. When a user adds/deletes an item I want the corresponding model to fade In/fade Out respectively. I have followed [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/fade-in-and-fade-out-animation-using-angularjs/) to implement the effects mentioned above. However, on page load all the models in the items fade in and not just when a new item in added using `$scope.items.push({item-x:item-value})`. I want the fade in effect only for the newly added items.

Also when when new items are pushed to the list on scroll(infinite-scroll), the items again fade-in.

Could this be achieved using `ng-class` directive on the html element?

Any help on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of what you've tried [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/)? ngAnimate has changed between Angular 1.2 and 1.3, so solutions will depend somewhat on what version you're using.

Comment: I am using AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.8.

Comment: Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2e7lOBHZKbi4a6coWojp?p=preview)

Comment: I forked your Plunker so that it uses 1.3.0-beta.9 http://plnkr.co/edit/dPYCIC6S5Ps06BV2nzaA?p=preview instead of 1.2.x, so now the animations work. It seems to behave the way you've requested - initial items appear without fade-in, while additional items do transition. Is there anything wrong with the behavior you see?

Comment: Is that so? I dont see the initial animation nor the animation when items are pushed or deleted from the list. My objective is I am loading initial data using an AJAX call to the server. I dont need to fadein items when i am loading initial items. Only when a user creates a new item using a form at the client, i need to fadein the new item created/deleted.

Comment: So in short what i am trying is to inject the ngAnimate service into my app conditionally and not while declaring the app. Is that even possible? Forgive me if I am being naive, these are still early days for me in Angular JS!

Comment: You're looking at the [forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dPYCIC6S5Ps06BV2nzaA?p=preview) and not seeing that behavior? I have tested in Chrome and Firefox, and now that I've just also added a few lines to cover disabling the animation for initial ajax load, it seems to work exactly as you have described.

Comment: Yes, I am looking at the forked plunker and its working now. Thats fantastic. Did not know about $animate.enabled('false'). So could this statement be called from any method inside the controller? Essentially what i have is items are added to the $scope.items list as the user scrolls down. So when a collection of new items is added at the bottom as a result of scrolling i dont need the items to fadein. Its only when a single item in added or deleted from the list. Alright, Thanks a lot for the inputs! I should be able to get it up and working in no time.

Comment: I just wrote up an answer that confirms the fact that you could use this for ngInfiniteScroll as well. Just disable animations at the start of your paging function, and then re-enable (inside of a $timeout) once the loading of the elements is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable animations globally using `$animate.enabled(/* boolean */)`. So, if you'd like to temporarily turn off animation during the initial loading of items, you could it like so:

```
$http.get('example.json').then(function(result){
    // disable animation
    $animate.enabled(false);
    $scope.itemslist = result.data
    // don't enable again until after browser renders
    $timeout(function(){ $animate.enabled(true); });
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dPYCIC6S5Ps06BV2nzaA?p=preview)

Notice that `$timeout` is necessary for re-enabling (and must be injected into the controller) in order for this to work.

You can use the same method for use with ngInfiniteScroll - just turn it off whenever you'd like. Just make sure that you turn it back on following the completion of the event you'd like to disable animations for.

Comment: Super! That was of great help! Thanks!

Comment: However, I encountered a strange behaviour. I am using $http.success(function(){} callback and the enabling/disabling of animations is taken care here. But it doesnt work!! Any reason why $http.then(function(){} works and .success doesnt?

Comment: Are you sure of that being the problem? Works here in the latest [update to the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dPYCIC6S5Ps06BV2nzaA?p=preview)